# C++ subclass using keyword question

Tags: c++, subclass

Say I have the following:

```
template<typename TemplateItem>
class TestA
{
    public:
        TemplateItem Item;

        void Function1(){;}
        void Function2(){;}
        void Function3(){;}
        void Function4(){;}
        //Etc etc number of functions is quite lengthy
};

template<typename TemplateItem>
class TestB : public TestA<TemplateItem>
{
    public:
        //How would I use the 'using' keyword to include everything from TestA
        //Without manually declaring it for 20 or more functions/variables individually
};
```

For those of you unfamiliar with template class inheritance problems:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.19

Some people still seem to think there is no such given heritance issue despite the above link stating to the contrary, but to quote from the above given site:

```
template<typename T>
 class B {
 public:
   void f() { }  ← member of class B<T>
 };

 template<typename T>
 class D : public B<T> {
 public:
   void g()
   {
     f();  ← bad (even though some compilers erroneously (temporarily?) accept it)
   }
};
```

> But there is an issue about how names are looked up.

**To clarify:**

The template-inheritance issue is **not** the problem, it's the *context* (so I don't get remarks like 'but so-and-so class does inherit'), the **problem is** the using keyword can only be applied to individual functions, which is tedious - I want to apply it to the entire TestA class, not have to write 20+ using keywords (which is still more efficient than appending 50+ this-> esque calls which might have to be modified anyway).

Comment: All those members are already public in the derived class, what is the problem exactly?

Comment: It's a template class. It does not inherit.

Comment: `class TestB : public TestA<TemplateItem>` isn't inheritance?

Comment: No, it isn't. See question. Updated. Surprised most people are unfamiliar with it.

Comment: Why isn't the first workaround in your linked parashift article working for you?

Comment: @SSight3: 1) its "class template" and 2) it does inherit, there is no difference to non-templates. maybe tell us what the real problem is, maybe with some code that exihibts the problem you are trying to solve (that is, when we compile it we can also see the error you talk about)

Comment: @SSight3: The page you linked describes a different problem. Post the code you experience actual problems with, not the code you *think* is wrong.

Comment: Not to mention that FAQ already has a solution that doesn't require you to sprinkle the declaration with `using`.

Comment: Using this-> is the same difference as I would have to include this-> at every instance when I simply want to inherit the functions. I don't want to waste time coding more than I have to. Heck, even the code that gives the problem is pretty much the same (except I don't declare any functions in TestB because it's about the *using* keyword ... one naturally assumes I will build functions for TestB).

Comment: I am shocked. First you guys think there is no inheritance problem (if there is no inheritance problem why is the FAQ states 'Why am I getting errors'), then when you admit there are, then you propose I post the problem, which I already have and the using keyword was suggested - I am not here to fix the template problem, I am here to find a way for the using keyword to be used beyond individual function calls.

Comment: The code you posted has no problem whatsoever. Stop assuming things and post the code that actually fails compilation.

Comment: @SSight3 : Because there __is__ no inheritance problem, there's a dependent name problem. Two very different things. And as @mkb asked, why isn't changing `f();` to `this->f();` sufficient for you?

Comment: The code is just pseudo code. It's not actually erroneous code. If you read the comments it asks about the using keyword's usage. Please learn to read people.

Comment: @ildjam Because it's not merely 'one' instance but 50+. And this won't be the only template derived classes... I don't expect to keep writing 'this->' 100+ times because the template class is having a heart attack over conventions. Consider: this->Size 50+, or using TestA::Size;. But then, why not just use-keyword all variables?

Comment: @SSight3 : If you're going to accuse people of not reading, you may want to consider the number of times people have told you that using is not necessary here, and not the best way to solve this problem.

Comment: "It's not actually erroneous code." Yeah, *that's the problem*.

Comment: @SSight3 I suggest you stop being belligerent and listen to the others when they say there is no problem. Create a simple test case with a single `Function0` instead of a multitude of them in `TestA`, then instantiate `TestB` within main and try to call `Function0` from the instance of `TestB`. Test this on the excellent [Comeau compiler](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/) and see if it complains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really really want to do this, why not make a *filename*.in and then create *filename* in your makefile or what have you with a shell script or a perl script or similar? That's been my approach for writing tedious code more than once.

Answer (score 5):

You've misunderstood what the FAQ is trying to explain. The name lookup problem happens within `TestB` when you're trying to call a member function from it's base class `TestA` because the latter's type is dependent on the template parameter. However, all of `TestA`'s public members are inherited by `TestB` and are visible to its callers.

When someone who is using `TestB` creates an instance of the class, say `TestB<int>`, then there is no more issue with name lookup since `TestA`'s dependent types have been resolved and you're free to call any of its public members.

If you were to call `TestA<T>::FunctionX()` from within one of `TestB`'s functions, that's when the name lookup problem arises. As the FAQ suggests, if you need to do this, just call the function as `this->FunctionX()` within `TestB`.

Comment: Basically, TestA's functions will be used by TestB. Long story short, TestB is an expansion to TestA (TestA is groundwork, TestB is the interface that provides the functionality). Which means TestB will be making a lot of calls to TestA. Typing this-> at every point is more tedious than using TestA::Function1, but typing 'using TestA::Function1' up until TestA::Function30 (naturally this is an example, the actual functions will have a variety of names) is very tedious as well (less than this->). Is there no singular call that does it all?

Comment: Not trying to be smug, but if writing `this->foo()` is too tedious then tough luck! That's like saying when you define the body of a member function writing `void Foo::Bar() { ... }` is too much typing and you'd rather write `void Foo:Bar() { ... }`. That's the rule defined by the language and you have to live with it. In this case, as the FAQ states, your compiler may not complain, especially if it is MSVC, because (last I heard) it doesn't actually do two phase name lookup.

Comment: void Foo::Bar() can be avoided by declaring the function inside the class. Not always tough luck.